# When using the Definiton of Derivative in a Proof...

Tags: proof-verification, derivatives

1) the question asks to prove $g'(a)=\frac{-f'(a)}{f^2(a)}$ given $g(x)=\frac1{f(x)}$. This proof is a short one in which you use the definition of the derivative and manipulate it

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{1/f(x)-1/f(a)}{x-a} = -\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{f(x)f(a)(x-a)} = -\frac{f'(a)}{f(x)f(a)}$$

once you sub in a for $x$ you get $f^2(a)$

However you are supposedly not allowed to sub in $x$ for $a$ at the end or it makes the proof wrong and I am unsure why. There isn't really anywhere else you can sub it in without ruining the manipulations. Before subbing it in I do assume that because $g$ is differentiable at a $g$ is continuous at a and therefore $f$ is both as well.

2) the question asks for prove $g$ is differentiable everywhere given for every $x, y\in R$, $g(x+y) = g(x) + 2xy +g(y)$. the question also tells you that $g(0) = 0$ and $g'(0) = c$ (some constant)

What I have done so far is sub $y$ as $h$ and apply the definition of the derivative I am just not sure where to go from there. I know the end result is supposed to give me $2x + c$ but I am not sure how

Comment: Thank you to whoever edited the question. How do you use latex on stack exchange? I tried using a "\" like I do on another site  but it didn't work

Comment: With code between $ signs

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are not supposed to substitute $x$ with $a$. The aim of your question is $g'(a)=-\frac{f'(a)}{f^2(a)}$. This equation actually assumes that $f'(a)$ exists, which implies $f$ is continuous at $a$. Therefore you can replace $x$ with $a$.

The answer to your second question is simple. Replace $y$ with $h\to0$, then
$$g(x+h)-g(x)=g(x)+2xh+g(h)-g(x)=2xh+g(h)$$
Then
$$g'(x)=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}=2x+\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(h+0)-g(0)}{h}$$
where $g(0)=0$. Since $g'(0)=c$, we have
$$g'(x)=2x+c<\infty$$
which means $g$ is differentiable $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.